# what will be the result if kafka topic file gets corrupted?

Tags: apache-kafka

What will happen if kafka topic log file gets corrupted. whether all previous messages will be lost? and what will happen to incoming messages ?

Answer (score 0):

If the Kafka cluster has more than one broker and topic has replication set up, the messages in the topic have copies on other broker. In such case for every message that is sent by producer the topic leader syncs it to the followers.

If the leader goes down the the Kafka selects one of the insync replicas as the leader and the consumers can use the corresponding leader for read and write.

to set replication on a topic

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 3 --partitions 1 --topic my-replicated-topic
```

More details about replication and various failure scenarios [here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#replication)

Comment: What if leader topic file is corrupted?

Comment: Kafka will elect a new leader for the topic if replication for topic partition is set up.